# Horizontal positioning with \includegraphics{}

Tags: graphics

Using `\includegraphics{}` from `graphicx`, I'm including this figure in my document:
[image]

Due to the long legend text, when the caption is centered underneath this, it's not centered under the graph region. Is there some way to adjust the horizontal positioning of the graphic rightwards?

Comment: I've always wanted to be able to export graphics like this with their bounding box shifted so the graphs themselves were centred and the legends, axes, etc, "hung out" of the figure. Never looked into doing it though; I suspect it'd be a big pain in Matlab or Mathematica. Best way would be to export the data to PGF and plot it there, but again, I'm not aware of a prebuilt way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you may be able to play with the horizontal positioning through `\hspace*{<length>}` command where `<length>` has to include units like `2cm`.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\hspace*{length}\includegraphics{}
\end{figure}
```

but it is probably not a good idea to have a legend on the side.

Comment: Well, long skinny graphic might not be the best idea in the first place but it's just an example. Side-legend is perfectly acceptable for lots of other kinds of plots (although I try and avoid legends where possible these days).

Comment: @Will: what do you use instead of a legend, then? Figure captions? Inline text inside the figure (next to the related data)? I’m just faced with such a situation …

Comment: Figure captions are worse than legends! I try to label the data directly on top of or next to the graph lines, but you need a bit of room and it takes much longer to design the graph.  Sometimes legends are unavoidable.

Comment: a few scientific journals ask to put the legend in the caption: is this very wrong? This way, you can save space and you do not have to hide a part of the graph with the legend

Comment: Nothing is "wrong" in this area :-) I just find putting info about the graph in its caption (a) tedious, (b) difficult to match the output style exactly, and (c) hard to maintain.

Comment: It is worth a new question for the community